# Ubuntu install doesn't run on 32Gb Nexus7 with 3g?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I tried installing Ubuntu on my recently purchased (for this purpose!) Nexus 7 32Gb, with the Cellular option.  When I rebooted with Ubuntu, it didn't come up.  I know, I need to post the errors I received.  I was in a hurry to get back to something usable for the holiday (on the road, Thanksgiving, etc.), so I just reinstalled Android for now.  When I have time, I'll post more of the errors.  All I remember right now is that it dropped into busybox and I didn't have a keyboard or any way to attach one.  (I used the 32Gb Ubuntu, by the way.)

Have others seen this?

Comment: Better to follow this in xda forum or android.stackexchange.com. Since  ubuntu installation Nexus 7 is not official and most users doesn't have the device or may not acquainted with the process. In XDA you will get step by step tutorial and can follow up easily.

Comment: Where did you buy a 64GB nexus7?  Google isn't selling one.  https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=nexus_7_16gb&feature=microsite&hl=en

Comment: I second @mfisch. WHERE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with the installation experts, I've discovered that the Quantal image for the 32GB Nexus7 with 3G is not currently working.  The reason is that the addition of the new radio device changed the devices around just enough that the tarball installer is looking at the wrong path to install the filesystem.  This is fixed in the raring images (which should be available shortly) but not quite yet on the Quantal images.

Comment: Ok, my bad.  It's the latest model 32Gb with cellular, which I'm using.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Sorry for my mistake re. memory size.  I'm still learning about fastboot, android, etc., and will be on watching for a new linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Check connectivity.

`sudo fastboot devices`

from: [wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation)