# Nexus 7 installer gets stuck on 'Erasing Boot Partition"

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have the 32 Gig version. I get as far as 'Erasing boot partition', at about 15-20% then it just hangs.

Comment: Is this device (Nexus 7) with or without 3G? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/220431/ubuntu-install-doesnt-run-on-32gb-nexus7-with-3g

Comment: wifi only... no 3G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only a problem on my virtual machine Ubuntu instance. I installed on a seperate machine (same image) and it worked ok.

Comment: That may be a connectivity issue, to device or Internet.